# How to create a pie chart in Vue Echarts?

Tags: vue.js, charts, data-visualization, pie-chart, echarts

I am working on VueJS and Vue Echarts library for creating data visualization.

Here is the demo of Polar chart from Vue Echarts:

Official Website: https://ecomfe.github.io/vue-echarts/demo/
GitHub Page: https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts

```
<template>
<v-chart :options="polar"/>
</template>

<style>
/**
 * The default size is 600px×400px, for responsive charts
 * you may need to set percentage values as follows (also
 * don't forget to provide a size for the container).
 */
.echarts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<script>
import ECharts from 'vue-echarts'
import 'echarts/lib/chart/line'
import 'echarts/lib/component/polar'

export default {
  components: {
    'v-chart': ECharts
  },
  data () {
    let data = []

    for (let i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        let t = i / 180 * Math.PI
        let r = Math.sin(2 * t) * Math.cos(2 * t)
        data.push([r, i])
    }

    return {
      polar: {
        title: {
          text: '极坐标双数值轴'
        },
        legend: {
          data: ['line']
        },
        polar: {
          center: ['50%', '54%']
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'axis',
          axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross'
          }
        },
        angleAxis: {
          type: 'value',
          startAngle: 0
        },
        radiusAxis: {
          min: 0
        },
        series: [
          {
            coordinateSystem: 'polar',
            name: 'line',
            type: 'line',
            showSymbol: false,
            data: data
          }
        ],
        animationDuration: 2000
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Result:
[Polar Chart Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lMm9.png)

I want to create Pie chart instead of polar. I checked several websites and I didn't find my results.

What I need is:
[this pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rXLK.png)

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes. Please check the codesandbox below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts/blob/master/src/demo/Demo.vue

You need to import the pie lib, as follows:

import 'echarts/lib/chart/pie'

Code Sandbox example at: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-echarts-pie-xu9wl?file=/src/components/Pie.vue